# For what interval does this power series converge and for what interval does it determine a differentiable function?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, power-series

> For what range of values of $x$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \dfrac{1}{n}(1+\sin x)^n$  converge?
>   Find with proof an interval on which it determines a differentiable function of $x$ and show that the derivative is $\cot(x)$.

**First Part**
Using Ration test, we get that the power series converges for all $$\left|1+\sin(x)\right|<1$$
which implies
$$-2<\sin(x)<0$$

**Second Part**
Now here I am not exactly too sure on how to proceed;
Differentiating the given function gives us
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(1+\sin x)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(1+\sin x)^n$$
But how do I show that this is $\cot(x)$?

Comment: You forgot the chain rule, the derivative has something you forgot. And use the formula for a geometric series.

Comment: Oh! how stupid of me, so now the derivative is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } cos(x)(1+sin(x))^n$=$cos(x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(1+sin(x))^n$. And by using the geometric formula i.e := $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } x^n=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ we now have  $cos(x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(1+sin(x))^n$ = $cos(x) \dfrac{1}{1-(1+sin(x))} = \dfrac{cos(x)}{-sin(x)}=-cot(x)$ but why is it negative, I can't seem to spot the mistake... the answer should be $cot(x)$

Comment: A hint for the last one: The mistake is not yours.

Comment: hmm...apologies of it seems obvious but I am confused now; so the method is correct?

Comment: Yes, the method is correct (you should be able to justify it, however), and, supposing you have not forgotten a sign in the transcription, the result is also correct, the derivative is $-\cot x$, not $\cot x$. The function is increasing on $[-\pi/2,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Also, 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \dfrac{1}{n}(1+\sin x)^n=-\ln(1-(1+\sin(x))=-\ln(-\sin(x))
$$
which again is valid for $\sin(x)<0$.